# Rails' Form Validation Wizardry

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I've been semi following along with the railstutorial, but with different functionality, different version of rails, and bootstrap 3 rather than 2, and I've made a signup form. It looks like this:

[image: signup form picture]

And it's even functional, it validates, hashes the password, all sorts of cool stuff. I'm liking rails. Anyway, I used scaffolding at first to set up the user table, but I've been doing everything manually since then to learn. So I'm not sure where the code is that's responsible for this:

[image]

I like that rails has yet again magically anticipated my wishes, but I want to make it look less god awful. And I don't know if the code that spawned this horrifying red mess is in bootstrap, or generated code, or the rails framework, or what.

So if somebody could explain this wizardry, that'd be cool. I'm not used to things just happening on my behalf.

Answer (score 1):

Check in scaffolds.css for a class called "field_with_errors"

You can also inspect in chrome and see the class name and what file it comes from.

Comment: I see. Do you know offhand how to make rails use the bootstrap "control-group-error" class instead? I see the class in the css, and I see it in the element, but I don't see the code that puts it around the form inputs.

Comment: if you are using simple form, check your simple form initializer.  the file is config/initializers/simple_form.rb   You will see the error class in the wrapper

Comment: Another quick way to find something like that is if you are using a text editor like sublime do a text search in your project for 'field_with_errors' and you will see it is in a couple spots.  One is the css file and the other is the initializer.  Just a pointer in case you overlooked doing something like this

Comment: I'm not using simple form unfortunately. And I just started with sublime text, thanks for the pointer. I didn't expect it to have something like that. I'm trying to figure out how to have the field_with_errors use bootstrap styling right now, should do the trick if I can figure it out. Thanks